# How to detect a web page blocker and then act on it?

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe, blocked

I have a website [here](http://flip-o-matic.net) and being a student in my school they block some website like Facebook but on my site I have a Facebook iframe.

So when I load the site in school I get the web blocker screen where the Facebook like button should be.

So is there anyway of detecting any web blocker and then if there is a web blocker disabling the iframe or the div it is in?

I don't know this is even possible but if anyone knows how it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to load any image or script from `facebook.com` and see if it gets an error.
(just make sure to change your code if Facebook changes their URLs)

Comment: Anything from Facebook seems to get blocked as long as it holds any relationship to Facebook it won't work. :(

Comment: I think you didn’t understand SLaks’ answer … if you _try_ loading an image, and that fails – then you know there’s no benefit in showing the iframe either. But if you’ll be able to _detect_ if an image from facebook.com could be loaded or not (JavaScript – load/error events on the image object) – that will depend on what your “web blocker” substitutes for it …